# Deja-Dup with encryption: disable Keyring

Tags: gnome-keyring, dejadup

I backup my data on an external drive using Deja-Dup. I chose to encrypt the backup. Now, every time I start my PC, Mint asks me to unlock my Keyring.

How can I grant my PC automatic access to the encryption password (and only to that)?